# Windows store app and iframe

Tags: javascript, html, windows, iframe, winjs

I have problem with Windows Store app and iframe.
Here is my code to load i frime in div element:

```
var iframe = element.querySelector(".item .item-link");
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(
    function () { iframe.innerHTML = item.content; }
);
```

And item.content is:

```
<iframe src="http://vk.com/video_ext.phpoid=222438792&id=166102206&hash=f81efa7780cef076&hd=1" width="90%" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Iframe is readed from url json data and added to data array.
That ifram have just white background and not display anything. What is wrong?

Comment: If you just embed it directly (not dynamically), does it work?

Comment: no, the result is the same :/

Comment: Then, what is the problem? Do no sites work, or just the one you specified?

Comment: No, not one link does not work. This iframe working on android app, website but not in windows store app...my question is why? No,

Comment: How are you hosting the iframe? I know iframes can work (as I've used them to host other sites), so it's something else about your code.

Comment: i read that iframes from url json data from my web host, i get all data and all data show and work perfectly except iframes... i've stored this data to data array.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?